# How to enable debug mode Civ 5 Mac OS X

Tags: civilization-5, macos

I know on pc i just set DebugPanel to 1 in the config .ini file but where does the config file live on Mac OS X when installing through Steam?

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac install of Civ 5 from Steam, the config file (and save game files) lives in the user's home directory under `Documents/Aspyr/Sid Meier's Civilization 5`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the full path is `~/"Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization 5/config.ini"`

Comment: No idea why these review people think it should be a comment, it's clearly an answer indicating yet another possible location for the config file to live on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

On some Macs, the config file is instead under:

> Library/Application Support/Civilization V